# Expecting member declaration error and Function invocation 'EditText(...)' expected error

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am getting this error on Android Studio which says "Expecting member declaration" on line 8 and "Function invocation 'EditText(...)' expected" on line 11. I am just trying to get the first name from the app UI (activity_main.xml) and save it in this variable. Can someone help me out and tell me what's going wrong ?

I am posting pictures of my code[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXY1g.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLPUP.jpg)

Tried getting Edit Text value from findViewById

Answer (score 0):

You are using Kotlin, not Java. The way you are doing is in Java.

To declare `EditText` variable in Kotlin, it can be:

```kotlin
lateinit var firstName: EditText
```

And the way to set the View to the `EditText`:

```kotlin
firstName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.simpleEditText1)
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/common-patterns).